# AWS EKS: Enabling Admission Controllers

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to enable some admission controllers on EKS. How do you see the existing admission controllers and enable new ones?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is possible at this time. The control plane is managed by Amazon, and it's not possible to modify it.

If you need a Kubernetes cluster in AWS with these kind of options, use [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)

Comment: Thanks. I am hoping AWS comes out with more flexibility in this arena

Comment: W.r.t. “see the existing admission controllers”, I could not find [any information](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/faq/) on what is included and whether it is more or less than the [standard recommendations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#is-there-a-recommended-set-of-admission-controllers-to-use).

Comment: As of October 12, 2018, Amazon has enabled this functionality for customers:  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-eks-enables-support-for-kubernetes-dynamic-admission-cont/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for the built-in admission controllers though - just dynamic ones. For example, how can you use pod security policies in EKS right now?