# How to enable PodNodeSelector admission controller in EKS version 1.15

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Can somebody point in the direction on how to enable `PodNodeSelector` admission controller in EKS version 1.15 ?

I'm trying to achieve what is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487333/how-to-assign-a-namespace-to-certain-nodes) link, but how to do this in Managed Kubernetes like EKS where you don't have access to control plane components.

Answer (score 8):

**In fact: You cannot enable `PodNodeSelector` in `EKS`.**

The fact that `EKS` is a Managed Kubernetes solution denies any reconfiguration of control plane components. That's why you cannot enable `PodNodeSelector`.

There is an official documentation about enabled admission controllers in EKS: [Aws.amazon.com: EKS: Userguide: Platform-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/platform-versions.html)

There is ongoing feature request for `PodNodeSelector` here (as well as some workarounds): [Github.com: AWS: Issue: 304](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/304).

There is an answer on StackOverflow with similar question [How to enable admission controllers in EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445477/12257134)